# The sum of the elements of an array

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream

I have a question for the following scenario;

I have `n-number` arrays in an `ArrayList`. The number of arrays is not predetermined, while the size of the array is fixed but it can contain null elements in it and the null values are considered as zero. I need to get the sum of each cell into the corresponding index in the new array, whose size is logically same as other arrays.

I tried to depict the scenario as follows;

[image]

I have a solution with classical way of iteration but I end up with a very dirty implementation. I would be happy to see your solution for this problem (preferably with `Stream api`)

Comment: Can you show your "dirty implementation"? Why is this dirty? What would a "clean" implementation look like?

Comment: @DatNguyen I have desinged the "dirty implementation" but not yet implemented. I meant with it that nested for-each loops, to calculate the result.

Comment: If the length of all arrays are known in advanced, I'd think of a simple solution with two `for` loops. Is that very "dirty"? Why would you prefer `Stream API`? What's the requirement?

Comment: @DatNguyen The requirement is not that I need to implement it with Stream api but until now, I have always seen that the solution with the stream api looks more compact. That is why, I preferred it.

Comment: What if all elements at a position are `null` (e.g. instead of the arrays starting with `12,9,null` they started with `null,null,null`? Is their sum `null`, `zero`?

Comment: @AndyTurner Null means zero in my case. That means the result for such a case will be zero.

Comment: Is it safe to assume the same number of items in each array? If yes, then I have a potential solution (though it will be written in vb.net)

Comment: @cMcNerlin no, only the size of the array is predetermined. Other infos will be decided on runtime.

Comment: Okay. I can work with that

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a way to do it, inspired by [shmosel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44880348/1876620):

```
Integer[] result = new Integer[FIXED_SIZE];
Arrays.setAll(result, i -> list.stream().mapToInt(a -> a[i] == null ? 0 : a[i]).sum());
```

---

Another way would be with a custom collector:

```
static <T> Collector<T[], ?, T[]> reducingByColumn(
        T identity,
        BinaryOperator<T> operator,
        IntFunction<T[]> factory) {

    return Collector.of(
        HashMap<Integer, T>::new,
        (map, a) -> IntStream.range(0, a.length)
            .forEach(i -> map.merge(i, a[i] == null ? identity : a[i], operator)),
        (m1, m2) -> {
            m2.forEach((k, v) -> m1.merge(k, v, operator));
            return m1;
        },
        map -> map.values().toArray(factory.apply(map.size())));
}
```

This collector uses a map to accumulate intermediate results.

You could use it as follows:

```
Integer[] result = list.stream()
    .collect(reducingByColumn(0, Integer::sum, Integer[]::new));
```

Comment: that's better and *way* more readable

Comment: That is so clever. Thank you for your effort and answer.

Answer (score 28):

A non-streams solution (because I don't think that an as-easily-understandable solution would be possible in streams):

```
int[] result = new int[n];  // n is the length of each array.
for (Integer[] array : arrays) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    // Increment the i-th element of the result by the i-th element of array.
    // Use 0 in place of null.
    result[i] += array[i] != null ? array[i].intValue() : 0;
    // or (suggested by shmosel)
    // if (array[i] != null) result[i] += array[i];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Here's a solution using streams:

```
final int SIZE = ...
List<Integer[]> arrays = ...
Integer[] result = IntStream.range(0, SIZE)
        .map(i -> arrays.stream()
                .map(arr -> arr[i])
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                .sum())
        .boxed()
        .toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

Comment: I would just say: this solution is compact, but I am not convinced it is readable. Certainly I'd have to spend a while sitting thinking about this if I found it in code I was reading.

Comment: @shmosel OP said "preferably". And in the same way that OPs frequently ask how to use regex for stuff better solved without a regex (without strongly justifying that preference), it's good to show alternatives.

Comment: `IntStream.of(0, SIZE)` will only give you the first and last elements, and will give you an index out of bounds exception.

Comment: It's nice, compact and clean, but it is really hard to read, but i prefer it over a straight iteration

Comment: @Michael Thanks, fixed.